# Accepted Protocol for answer acceptance

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Consider this question:

[Restore Backup to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436344/restoring-sql-server-backup-to-azure-sql-database)

At the time I accepted the answer, the *currently* accepted answer was the best answer.  **Today**, there is a better answer *due to advancement in the technology*.

Should I update the accepted answer to the more relevant (*better now*) answer or leave it as is?

What is best for new user's who come across the question?

Comment: It's up to you. Simply accept the answer that helped you most or that you think is the best.

Comment: @Servy this isn't a duplicate, at least IMO.  This is a case where tech advances caused for a better answer to come along.

Comment: @MisterPositive And that situation is covered in the answers to that question.

Comment: @Servy I did not see my specific case in the answers, but at this point I lost interest.  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) provides some guidance (emphasis mine):

> **Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly.** It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally. Not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they might not change the accepted answer even if a newer, better answer comes along later.

It's totally fine to accept a different answer later on. It's also totally fine to not accept a different answer, it's completely up to you.